# How to build a custom 'stageros' using catkin?

Tags: simulation, catkin, stageros, build, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Due to stageros does not fit all my requirements, I need to do some modifications to source code. My questions are:

What files should I add to my package?
How should I modify CMakelists.txt in my new package for build the modified stageros.cpp?
Do I have to add libstage library to my package?

I'm using ROS Groovy on Ubuntu 12.04.

Thanks,

Gustavo.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61493/how-to-build-a-custom-%27stageros%27-using-catkin?/) by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 756 on 2013-04-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally stage was splited in ros-hydro-stage and ros-hydro-stage-ros in hydro, so I could modify stage-ros and it depends on stage.

---

Originally posted by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) with karma: 756 on 2014-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Groovy version of stage still uses rosbuild. Consequently, catkin packages can't depend on it.

Many packages are being converted to catkin for Hydro. Stage has not yet been released to Hydro alpha, I don't know whether it will be converted then or not.

You *can* create your own modified version of `stageros` with rosbuild. I had a similar problem with [simulator_art](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_art), you can [look at my solution here](http://utexas-art-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/tags/distros/fuerte/stacks/art_vehicle/simulator_art/). That package depends on `libstage` and has its own modified copy of `stageros.cpp`.

The only problem is that I've had to modify it every time they change the stage API, with is unfortunately frequent.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-04-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-04-26**:
When you say that I can create modified version using rosbuild is for create a dependency from stage stack? I mean... this is for avoiding include libstage in my new package?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-04-26**:
No, it depends on the stage package, using its libstage and stage.hh, but compiles its own copy of stageros.cpp (mine variant is called `artstage.cc`).

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-04-26**:
sorry,may be I did not explain well... Using rosbuild I can create my custom-stage depending on stage package, using its libstage and stage.hh. But if I want to use catkin, I have to add libstage and stage.hh to my package, isn't it?

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-04-26**:
In this way I could preserve certain version of libstage for my simulator package and not depend on stage releases..

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-04-26**:
I repeat: catkin packages *cannot* depend on rosbuild packages. Stage in Groovy is a rosbuild package. What you want does not work.

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-04-26**:
Hi @joq this what I did: https://github.com/gustavovelascoh/vintersim